# Prove a triangle is equilateral

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I have to prove that a triangle is equilateral given that there is a unit circle inscribed in the triangle and that the triangle's heights are integers.

I'm unsure on how to proceed with the question. My attempts at proving this end up in dead ends.

Edit: As requested, one of my dead ends (at least the one I think is closest to the right answer)

A unit circle inscribed in triangle ABC touches the it at the midpoints of line AB, line BC, and line AC (from now on I'll denote them by M, N, and P respectively). The height of the trangle is the line AN, which passes through the unit circle through its origin. Therefore, $$h = \overline{AN} = 2+x $$ where x is the measurement of the line between A and the top of the unit circle. X is also an integer since the question says the height has to be an integer.

This is where I reached a dead end

Comment: Then post one of your dead ends. We will find new roads for you.

Comment: edited my original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p$ and $A$ be the perimeter and the area of the triangle.

1) We have that
$$\frac{1}{r}=\frac{p}{2A}=\frac{a}{2A}+\frac{b}{2A}+\frac{c}{2A}=
\frac{1}{h_a}+\frac{1}{h_b}+\frac{1}{h_c}$$
where $a$, $b$, $c$ are the sides,  $h_a$, $h_b$, $h_c$ are the corresponding altitudes and $r$ is the radius of the inscribed circle.

2) The triangle inequality $a<b+c$ implies
$$\frac{1}{h_a}=\frac{a}{2A}<\frac{b}{2A}+\frac{c}{2A}=\frac{1}{h_b}+\frac{1}{h_c}.$$

Hence, by 1) and 2), any altitude is longer than the diameter of the incircle:
$$\frac{1}{h_a}<\frac{1}{h_b}+\frac{1}{h_c}=r-\frac{1}{h_a}\quad
\Rightarrow\quad  h_a>2r.$$ 
Since $r=1$ then $h_a>2r=2$. Moreover $h_a\geq 3$ because $h_a$ is an integer.

In a similar way, we obtain $h_b\geq 3$, $h_c\geq 3$.

By 1) we have that $h_a=h_b=h_c=3$ (otherwise $\frac{1}{h_a}+\frac{1}{h_b}+\frac{1}{h_c}<1$) and finally
$$a=\frac{2A}{h_a}=\frac{2A}{3},\; b=\frac{2A}{h_b}=\frac{2A}{3},\;c=\frac{2A}{h_c}=\frac{2A}{3}$$
which means that the triangle is equilateral.

Comment: @JeremyF99 I edited my answer with all the details. Is it clear now?

Comment: Definitively wouldn't of thought of it like that, thank you!

Comment: @JeremyF99 You are welcome! Very nice problem.

Comment: +1. Nicely done. I *want* to say that you could simplify the argument a bit by observing how it's "obvious" that any altitude is longer than the diameter of the incircle ... but, then again, it's not *completely* obvious, and justification would take about as much effort as your approach, so .. nevermind. ;)

Comment: @Blue Thank you for your comment. I edited my answer by putting in evidence your remark.